# Compare dates and change colours

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that compares actual date with dates values in a column, when the workbook is opened. It changes interior and font color if the date value of a cell is less than the actual date. The macro worked perfectly, but I did some general changes and now it is not working at all.

The interior and font color doesn't change if the cell value was inserted by Si.Value=True condition.

The macro with which I insert dates:

```
Private Sub Insertar_Click()

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("ControlVentas")

ultimafila = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

With ws2

If Si.Value = True Then
        .Cells(ultimafila, 5) = fecha_cambio
        'fecha_cambio is a Month View
Else
        .Cells(ultimafila, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=DATE(YEAR(RC[-1])+1,MONTH(RC[-1]),DAY(RC[-1]))"
End If

End With

End Sub
```

The macro with which I compare dates is:

```
Sub Iniciar()

Dim i As Long
Dim uf As Long

fechaActual = Date

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ControlVentas").Activate
uf = Range("E3", Range("E3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("E3").Select

For i = 1 To uf

    If ActiveCell.Value < fechaActual Then
        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 185, 185)
        ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(204, 0, 0)
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next

Range("B1").Select

End Sub
```

Part of Full macro:

```
Sub Iniciar()

Dim i As Long
Dim uf As Long

fechaActual = Date

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ControlVentas").Activate
uf = Range("E3", Range("E3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("E3").Select

For i = 1 To uf

    If ActiveCell.Value < fechaActual Then
        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 185, 185)
        ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(204, 0, 0)
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Selection.Copy
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next

Range("B1").Select

End Sub


Sub insertar()
Dim dblEndTime As Double

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Nuevo").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 95, 9)
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Nuevo").Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(50, 95, 9)

dblEndTime = Timer + 0.1
Do While Timer < dblEndTime
    DoEvents
Loop

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Nuevo").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(85, 131, 53)
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Nuevo").Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(85, 131, 53)

UserForm1.UserForm_Initialize
UserForm1.Show

End Sub


Sub Cambio_realizado()
Dim contador As Double
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Set ws3 = Worksheets("ControlVentas")
Dim dblEndTime As Double
fechaActual = Date

If ActiveCell.Column = 5 Then
    If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveCell.Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, ActiveCell.Value)

        If ActiveCell.Value < fechaActual Then
            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 185, 185)
            ActiveCell.Font.Color = RGB(204, 0, 0)
        Else
            If ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 185, 185) Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
                Selection.Copy
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Else
            End If
        End If

        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Cambio").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 95, 9)
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Cambio").Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(50, 95, 9)
        'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
        'ActiveCell = ActiveCell + 1
        'ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Select
        If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1) = 13641 Or Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1) = 13651 Or Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1) = 1377 Then
            ws3.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8) = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 8) + 1
        Else
        End If

        Select Case Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
            Case Is = 13641
                If ws3.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 9) = 0 Then
                    ws3.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6) = "13845 - 13847"
                Else
                    ws3.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6) = "13845 - 13848"
                End If
            Case Is = 1377
                If ws3.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 9) = 0 Then
                    ws3.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6) = "1372 - 1374 - 1386"
                Else
                    ws3.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6) = "1372 - 1373 - 1374"
                End If
            Case Is = 13651
                If ws3.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 9) = 0 Then
                    ws3.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6) = "1370 - 1374 - 13847"
                Else
                    ws3.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 6) = "1370 - 1374 - 13848"
                End If
            Case Else
        End Select
     Else
     MsgBox ("Este registro está vacío." + Chr(13) + "Seleccione un registro con fecha.")
    End If
Else
MsgBox ("Seleccione un dato de la columnna 'Fecha cambio repuestos'")
End If

dblEndTime = Timer + 0.1
Do While Timer < dblEndTime
    DoEvents
Loop

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Cambio").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(85, 131, 53)
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Cambio").Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(85, 131, 53)

End Sub


Sub eliminar()
Dim dblEndTime As Double
On Error Resume Next
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete

ActiveSheet.Shapes("Eliminar").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 95, 9)
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Eliminar").Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(50, 95, 9)
dblEndTime = Timer + 0.1
Do While Timer < dblEndTime
    DoEvents
Loop
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Eliminar").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(85, 131, 53)
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Eliminar").Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(85, 131, 53)

End Sub


Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cod As Range
Dim pro As Range
Dim cli As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws5 As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("ListaProductos")
Set ws5 = Worksheets("ListaClientes")

codigo.Clear
For Each cod In ws.Range("CodigoProductoLista")
    With Me.codigo
        .AddItem cod.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cod.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End With
Next cod

cliente.Clear
For Each cli In ws5.Range("ClienteLista")
    With Me.cliente
        .AddItem cli.Value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cli.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End With
Next cli

No.Value = True
calendario2.Visible = False
calendario2.Refresh
calendario = Date
Me.codigo.SetFocus
End Sub


Private Sub calendario2_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
fecha_cambio = calendario2
End Sub


Private Sub calendario_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
fecha_compra = calendario
End Sub


Private Sub Si_Click()

If Si.Value = True Then
    calendario2.Visible = True
    calendario2.Refresh
    Label8.Visible = True
    fecha_cambio.Visible = True
Else
End If

End Sub


Private Sub No_Click()

If No.Value = True Then
    calendario2.Visible = False
    calendario2.Refresh
    Label8.Visible = False
    fecha_cambio.Visible = False
Else
End If

End Sub


Private Sub Insertar_Click()

If IsNumeric(codigo) = False Then
    codigo.Value = ""
    MsgBox ("Ingrese un número en 'Código'")
    producto = Empty
    Me.codigo.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim ultimafila As Long
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("ControlVentas")
Dim codi As Integer

ultimafila = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
penultima = ultima - 1

With ws2

    If codigo.Text <> "" Then
        Me.producto.SetFocus
    Else
        MsgBox ("Ingrese el código del producto")
        Me.codigo.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If producto <> "" Then
        Me.cliente.SetFocus
    Else
        MsgBox ("Ingrese el nombre del producto")
        Me.producto.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If cliente.Text <> "" Then
        Me.fecha_compra.SetFocus
    Else
        MsgBox ("Ingrese el nombre del cliente")
        Me.cliente.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If fecha_compra = Empty Then
        fecha_compra = Date
    Else
        fecha_compra = fecha_compra
    End If

    .Cells(ultimafila, 1) = Val(codigo)
    .Cells(ultimafila, 2) = producto
    .Cells(ultimafila, 3) = cliente
    'Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    .Cells(ultimafila, 4) = fecha_compra
    'Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy;@"

    If Si.Value = True Then
        .Cells(ultimafila, 5) = fecha_cambio
        'fecha_cambio is a Month View
    Else
        .Cells(ultimafila, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=DATE(YEAR(RC[-1])+1,MONTH(RC[-1]),DAY(RC[-1]))"
    End If

    No.Value = True

    If .Cells(ultimafila, 1) = 13641 Or .Cells(ultimafila, 1) = 13651 Or .Cells(ultimafila, 1) = 1377 Then
        .Cells(ultimafila, 8) = 1
    Else
    End If

    Select Case codigo
        Case Is = 13501
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6) = "13503"
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6).Select
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Case Is = 1359
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6) = "13581"
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6).Select
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Case Is = 1377
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6) = "1372 - 1373 - 1374"
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6).Select
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Case Is = 13631
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6) = "1372 - 1374"
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6).Select
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Case Is = 13641
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6) = "13845 - 13848"
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6).Select
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Case Is = 13651
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6) = "1370 - 1374 - 13848"
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6).Select
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Case Is = 1441
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6) = "1444"
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6).Select
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Case Is = 1438
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6) = "1439"
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6).Select
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Case Is = 1466
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6) = "14661"
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6).Select
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Case Is = 14662
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6) = "13831"
            .Cells(ultimafila, 6).Select
            Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Case Else
    End Select

    .Cells(ultimafila, 7) = observaciones

End With

codigo = Empty
producto = Empty
cliente = Empty
fecha_compra = Empty
fecha_cambio = Empty
observaciones = Empty

UserForm1.UserForm_Initialize

End Sub
```

Comment: Where does fechaActual get declared as a variable?

Comment: It isn't. Should I declare it as double?

Comment: Your code worked for me just as you have it here but you should follow the advise Scott gave you try to use the application objects themselves rather than using the application to do everything for you.

Comment: Thanks! I realized why the macro is not changing intenrior and font color of some dates. I updated the post. Can you take a look again?

Comment: Where does the top code go is it in another sub? and why is there an unqualified reference .Cells?

Comment: Yes it is another sub. It's a huge macro so I did not paste all. I updated it

Comment: Do you still need help with this code or is it working?

Comment: It isnt. The interior and font color doesn´t change if the cell value was inserted by Si.Value=True condition.

Comment: Can you post the complete code because si is not declared in the portion that I have and it is difficult for me to see the complete picture.

Comment: Also check to make sure your regional settings in windows is set to the style you want on date format.  The issue is most likely how the date is being formatted.  Excel uses windows regional settings as default.

Comment: I have checked it. But the issue remains. I posted the code. The weird is: when date in the cell is inserted with `fecha_cambio` (`Si.Value=True`), its interior and font color wont be changed if workbook is closed/opened. But, when the date in the cell is inserted with `.FormulaR1C1` (`Else`), its interior and font color will change if workbook is closed/opened. Besides, if I change date wiht `Sub Cambio_realizado()`, its interior and font color will change if workbook is closed/opened.

Comment: What type of object is the calendario2_DateClick? I want to recreate some of the objects you have to see if I can get the same result that you are getting. I suspect it is a problem with variable types.

Comment: It's a MonthView object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close

You did a great job trying to use the macro recorder and fixing it to do what you want.

A couple of things:

1 If you are going to loop, use the loop to choose the next cell then you do not need to actually select it and use activecell

2 Try and avoid using `.Select` it slows down the subroutine.

Try this:

```
Sub Iniciar()

Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cel As Range

fechaActual = Date

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ControlVentas")

For Each cel In ws.Range(ws.Range("E3"), ws.Range("E3").End(xlDown).offset(-1))

    If cel.value < fechaActual Then
        cel.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 185, 185)
        cel.Font.Color = RGB(204, 0, 0)
    Else
        cel.Interior.Color = cel.offset(,-1).Interior.Color
        cel.Font.Color = cel.offset(,-1).Font.Color
    End If


Next cel
```

I changed the else statement to copy the interior color and text color from the cell to the left.  If the left cell does not indicate the correct color scheme try you can change the offset number either further to the left by increasing the -1 lower or change it positive and it will look right.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! Data is in a table with style so each row has a diferent interior color, thats the reason for in `Else` I copy previous column format.

Comment: @WilsonMéndezPeñalosa I fixed the coloring on the else.  I hope you can find and answer to your other issue.

Comment: @WilsonMéndezPeñalosa That is probably because it is a table and it registers the last empty row.  I have changed the code.

Comment: Hi, I've just tried the code, but it evaluates one row more than necessary, how can I substract 1?

Comment: Thanks! But there is a last issue, to all cells whose condition is false it should copy the format of previus column, but it set interior color to white, and font color to black. Like a default cell.

Comment: Ok. I think the issue is because it is a table with style, but I dont' know how to fix it.

Comment: @WilsonMéndezPeñalosa I have changed it see my edited post for notes.

Comment: Ok. The macro copies the interior and font color from the left cell, but it still copying white interior and black font. Data is in a table with style so I used property `.Interior.ThemeColor`, and it worked. Thank you very much for your help!